# How to infer type parameters from other type parameters?

Tags: typescript

I want to implement a sorting function that can take the value of an object using a function, but at the moment I can't infer the return value of the function that takes the value.

```
type TKey<TData> = ((data: TData) => any)

interface SortingConfig<
  TData,
  TExtractor extends TKey<TData>,
  TValue =
    TExtractor extends (data: TData) => infer R ? R : never> {
  extractor: TExtractor,
  comparator?: (a: TValue, b: TValue) => number
}

function test1<TData, TExtractor extends TKey<TData>>(
  value: TData,
  conf: SortingConfig<TData, TExtractor>
) {}

test1({
  a: 1,
  b: "string"
}, {
  // extractor type: (data: {a: number, b: string}) => string
  // The type of comparator is wrong, parameter type should be the return type of extractor
  extractor: data => data.b,
  // comparator type: (a: any, b: any) => any
  // expect: (a: string, b: string) => number
  comparator: (a, b) => a
})

/**
 * This works, but unfortunately I need to write it in the above way
 */
function test2<
  TData,
  TExtractor extends TKey<TData>,
  TValue = TExtractor extends (data: TData) => infer R ? R : never
>(
  data: TData, 
  extractor: TExtractor, 
  comparator: (a: TValue, b: TValue) => number
) {}

// Put the comparator and extractor outside the conf object and it works
// extractor type: (data: {a: number, b: string}) => number
// comparator type: (a: number, b: number) => number
test2({a: 1, b: "string"}, data => data.a, (a, b) => a)
```

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKg0hEAeGARAhsdA+KBeKACkIBNN0AuWDLASn13QDsRaAoNgSyeAgCcAZugDG0AMoB7PsG4BzAMISmAzrKRso1cgBoNsAKIAPYHxHApUCMYhMSAZ1gJkactl2aYANXQAbAK7QeHoeRiZmFla8tg6k5FQudAxQ3AL8UABKUAD8GVBUTBAAbvy4AN56kabC5nzxoVU17lDCEgC2YOimNVlUhJSw3v4Q2lAARvGDAfR4uEx+raP8bAC+HAJ+TNWcSlC8dsAAjCg06CMw9eF8ltbRjojHrtiEeoW+AfEnTS3KVJLScoplKoHlgzhdqlJsGx6KVVmw9odCOVNP0Dk1xlAAET7PhyTErEbIqAAemJ1zCEKuoEgvTIWCopX6cwW-BGGJxcmW01wHKYsj0pNgAAtoNToBIBM02h0uhZOA4AO58JSyEYy9CtCC8KngaB2IUSPw+EhjUUiqB8LV+PhMXa6qAS8kNKQVYzO2pQOnoJJegB0oyagpa7U6mAsYt6-WYIDZVGj3Kg0YFZKskGqkaovNVY0zJjkCeZiz4emD6pqkbZCfQK3YbGJACp6xp68L5VAFVIANZ2Nl+YBQDYCKTADaYCA+EBQACSUAKEBN5nbuN4yX73F25vQowkxXb6BAzeJbHWmxkOwRACZ1B5Pnpzm7LuSbPY7s4Tm475NAgYH5Sn7dYnpLREhmZJlDSTIckyfIiiWJ49C9D4dCgV0KXLH80KkEYS2lUN0L6CY3mGHMBiIgt5iLaEoFhDhBQABT7DdoFLPCLGYE1KkfQ1gDsTgSDNZilElCRRgAKwgapE1sVd2y7Ow6xTX8ajtGkiEQ6imQo1kSKzLkkkLJYg1w2UdVUgjZy0vhYwslk+HI2z4QgfYLyRVFrOxPM+UxZYRi9H1yF9U4iCC0Yq1oIA)

====================================================

Thanks @jcalz for pointing out. I sacrifice the inference of `extractor`, to have the comparator inferred.

```
function test1<TData, TValue>(
  value: TData,
  conf: {
    extractor: (data: TData) => TValue,
    comparator: (a: TValue, b: TValue) => number
  }
) {}

test1({
  a: 1,
  b: "string"
}, {
  // Now you have to supply the type for data (and if you forget, any is frustratingly inferred)
  extractor: (data: { a: number, b: string }) => data.b,
  comparator: (a, b) => a.localeCompare(b)
})
```

Comment: Please be more specific about what "this works" and "this doesn't" means - I see no errors in the code, what is the expected vs. actual result?

Comment: @kaya3 Cannot infer the type of comparator

Comment: You're hitting the problem in [microsoft/TypeScript#38872](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38872); inference does not work the way you want, unfortunately.  My suggested workaround would be something like your `test2`, but you say you "need" to write it the other way.  Would [this](https://tsplay.dev/BmxKGN) meet your need?  If so, I'll write up an answer. If not, please elaborate on why it doesn't (preferably with a [mcve] of the use case) and maybe I can think of something else.